# Assign model with a different model in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am new to `backbone.js`.

I'm storing a model value in a variable like belo

`window.oldModel=this.model`

When user modifies the data synchronusly, I'm displaying live preview to the user and if he clicks on the save changes then I'm submiting the data. But if he clicks on discards the changes then I'm assigning the model with previous model  like below

`this.model=window.oldModel`

This does not reflect the data on the page, I need to refresh the page to see the old values but I want to the changes to be effected immediately.

Answer (score 0):

A model is a JavaScript object, thus when you assign `window.oldModel` to `this.model` it is keeping a reference - and not an actual copy of your model. Changes will always reflect in both.

Depending on your app, you need to either save the models attributes:

```
window.oldModel = {
  attribute1 : this.model.get('attribute1'),
  attribute2 : this.model.get('attribute2')
  // and so on ...
};
```

and then reset it with

```
this.model.set({
  attribute1 : window.oldModel.attribute1,
  attribute2 : window.oldModel.attribute2
  // ....
});
```

Or, which is probably easier, `clone` your model (http://backbonejs.org/#Model-clone) instead:

```
window.oldModel = this.model.clone();
```

and then just assign it when needed as you did before.

Comment: Looking gud,will try it